# Number of digits and which digits it is in integer

Tags: java, int

Example `int i=185;`

Then I want to get that 'i' contains 3 digits and those digits are 1,8, and 5.

Comment: Is this homework?  Is it a self-learning exercise?  Something like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1st solution:

```
/**
 * Using Integer/String classes functionality
 */
public class Shweta {

    private static Integer i = 185;

    public static void main(String... args) {
        String iStr = i.toString();
        for (char digit : iStr.toCharArray()) {
            System.out.println(digit);
        }
        System.out.println("Length is: " + iStr.length());
    }

}
```

2nd solution:

```
/**
 * Doing that in a 'homework' way
 */
public class ShwetaNoCheats {

    private static Integer i = 185;

    public static void main(String... args) {
        int length = 0;
        while (i != 0) {
            System.out.println(i - (i / 10) * 10);
            i /= 10;
            length++;
        }
        System.out.println("Length is: " + length);
    }
}
```

Comment: No +1 - you've given the OP a potted solution, so he / she doesn't have to think.

Comment: This code only outputs answer to console, integrating this function with the rest of the program is still should be done by author of question. Agree that it's somehow potted solution though.

Comment: @Petro: It was an assignment, I believe. Which is already submitted now, after your courtesy. ;)

Answer (score 8):

**Hint:** You need to take the modulus of the number by 10, to get the last digit. And then divide the same number by 10, do get the first two numbers. Repeat yourself as many times as required.

Answer (score 2):

The easy way to do this is by converting to a locale-agnostic string, then looking at each character in the string. I am not giving the final solution in case this is homework, but here are some important APIs...

Converting to string:

```
String stringForm = Integer.toString(number);
```

Handling negatives:

```
int nonNegative = Math.abs(number);
```

Length of a string:

```
int length = stringForm.length();
```

Getting the i-th character of a string:

```
char c = stringForm.charAt(i);
```

Comment: +1 - for helping the OP learn by not giving him/her a potted solution,

Answer (score 0):

One way would be:

```
int i = 185;

int a = i / 100;         // 1
int b = (i % 100) / 10;  // 8
int c = i % 10;          // 5
```

But i think you need something more generic? Try via string

```
int i = 185;
String iAsString = String.format("%d", i);

if(iAsString.contains("1")){
   // do something...
}
```

And more advanced:

```
    int i = 185;
    String iAsString = String.format("%d", i);

    HashSet<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
    for(char c : iAsString.toCharArray()){
        set.add(Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(c)));
    }
```

Then you can work on the set.

Comment: if i have only two digit or 1 digit then how can it be dome??example instead of i=185if i have i=20 or i=5 then??

Comment: then use the second way via string.

Answer (score 0):

The number of decimal digits is also given by Math.ceil(Math.log10(i)), for integral `i`.